# How to add face in a looped edge

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces, object-mode, loop

[image: Blender - Face in a looped edges in a curve]

Greetings.

I am experiment in Blender and I work on a project, I would like to ask.

How can I add a face to this looped edge?

Comment: Please tell us.. is this a curve? Is it 2D?

Comment: How was the edge produced? - If it's a curve, use the Object > Convert > Mesh menu in Object mode, go into Edit mode, select All and then hit F.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, it is a curve.

Comment: @JohnEason I did it, but face did not show up.

Comment: I just have discovered New face from edges button, otherwise thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure where you found that button? The method I suggested using the F key is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/make_face_edge.html#new-edge-face-from-vertices) but would only work after you converted the curve to a mesh.

Comment: Hello, it's not clear if it's a curve or a mesh, if it's a curve you need to choose Shape > 2D and Fill Mode >Front for example. If it's a mesh, select all the vertices and press F to fill, as John says, not sure what the New Face you've done is exactly, also it might be good to know what is your whole project to make sure that you're choosing the best way